# image viewer for windows that doesn't play slideshows in full screen

Tags: windows-10, slideshow, image-viewer

on linux I had a good image viewer that could run a slide show in multiple instances simultaneously but on windows I can't find anything that doesn't force your image viewer into full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/) is a great photo viewer. It will show individual photos, it has a full-screen display or part screen with menus and toolbars. It has 'next' and 'previous' photo commands in both modes. It can do slide shows.

It works fine on Windows 10.

Comment: it's important that it doesn't force the view into full screen when you start the slideshow.  I would prefer it to just do the slideshow in windowed view, does Irfanview do that?

Comment: Yes, it supports slideshow within the window view without forcing for full screen. There are navigation button to move forward and backward.

Comment: Does this solution serve your purpose?

Comment: yes, thank you, I have not tried the program yet but I have it noted for next time I wish to have that circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

another solution is [HoneyView](https://www.bandisoft.com/honeyview/)
has some benefits over Irfanview, but also some disadvantages.
Try both and see which one is best for your needs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).